# Is there a way to edit HTML in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

as an example

```
<div>
<h5>title1</h5>
<h3>subtitle1</h3>
</div>
```

at

```
<div>
<h3>title2</h3>
<h1>subtitle2</h1>
</div>
```

I want to modify HTML code like

- Crawl certain websites and modify certain HTML code

I wanted to build my own automation program, but I couldn't find anything related to it while looking for it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I want to do is apply the D-Day counter to my profile in Discord using selenium. @Community

Comment: Selenium is just a programmable web browser. Can you edit HTML using your web browser?

Comment: However, if you check the HTML code of the content editing area of ​​Discord, you need to edit the html code because it is in the form of a div, not an input tag.

Comment: You could modify the HTML in the page but it's not going to stay as soon as the page is refreshed/updated in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used JS to modify some HTML elements from python with the `driver.execute_script` command. 
While googling I've also noticed that nowadays more people tend to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for such tasks.